# Is it possible to test an NServicebus saga that a timeout has not been set?

Tags: nservicebus

I have a scenario where I want to make sure that a timeout has not been set, is that possible?

Should I use `ExpectNotSent` for that?

Answer (score 1):

We don't have explicit support for "ExpectNoTimeoutsToBeSet" yet. Since timeouts results in a bus.Defer I don't think ExpectNotSent would work either.

Would you be able to log a GitHub issue for this so that we can fix it?